# iOS Bluetooth Central Manager

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I am trying out the iOS Bluetooth Central Manager on my iPhone.

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    // Determine the state of the peripheral
    if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");
    }
}
```

It always goes to the hardware is unsupported choice.

Also, I able to send picture between Android Phones through bluetooth, but when I am trying to send to my iPhone, it got rejected. Is iOS bluetooth a closed one?  It won't work with other Bluetooth devices?

Comment: Was the answer below correct?

Comment: are you running on simulator?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your iOS device just doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy.

The only supported iOS devices are iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, iPhone 5c, iPhone 5s, iPad 3rd Gen, iPad 4th Gen, iPad air, iPad mini, and iPod Touch 5th Gen (and newer devices).